# KosherLamp closed by window (Moris Ayin?)

Tags: halacha, shabbat, lighting, marit-ayin

Was wondering if closing the [KosherLamp](http://www.kosherimage.com/kosherlampMAX.html) on Shabbat while a window shade is up when it is dark and possible onlookers can see a light go off in ones house constitute a case of *moris ayin* (doing something that is permitted, in a way that might appear to onlookers as doing something forbidden, which is generally discouraged in Judaism). Especially if one were to close the window shades quickly right after. I'm aware these days people are aware of automated lights which I'm guessing is one reason it most likely wouldn't be but does one still have to be careful regarding not showing subsequent actions such as closing the shades thereafter?

Comment: Interesting question, +1

Comment: you answered your own question,since people use timers and such,no one will suspect you did melacha.

Comment: the subsequent manual action makes it look like the initial automated action are connected. In this case both were manual and permissible anyhow except if moris ayin plays a part.

Answer (score 5):

Rabbi Moshe Feinstein actually addressed a similar concern, *Maris Ayin* with regards to your lights on timers -- an onlooker will see your dining room suddenly -- *click!* -- lit up. He allowed it; so I'd assume the same should apply here.

Comment: +1, 'cuz I'm pretty sure you're right....but inserting a more specific מראה מקום would improve this answer.